# Ionic Notifications Listener, implementation

Tags: android, ios, notifications, ionic-framework

Currently, I have created a project that consists of a app that connects my phone to an Arduino through a Bluetooth module. I have successfully made a reliable connection between the two, and now I want to have a script/something that sends a 10 second light blinking to a led connected to the Arduino whenever the phone gets a notification. This seemed simple enough, until I looked into how to do so, and found **BroadcastReciever.** Is there a Broadcast Reciever that works for **all notifications** that a system gets, may it be incoming call, sms, or app information sent through notification?

If anyone has any ideas that are not **Broadcast Reciever** related, i'm all ears.

Comment: You can't receive any notifications for apps other than your own in iOS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've been scouring the web and have found this to be true, also. Seems like a slight downside to Ionic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing that you want to know when a notification arrives. For this,  you may need something called NotificationListener. Hope following API helps:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html

**Update:** 
I missed Ionic earlier. So for Cordova, following is the Cordova plugin (Android) you can try. It has example usage in README file:

https://github.com/coconauts/NotificationListener-cordova

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! My issue is, the way i learned how to make apps so far has been limited: using cordova plug ins and the Ionic index (html) and app (java) files in order to do my programming. i wouldn't even know where to start with this one, as it doesn't seem to come in a plugin that would be ionic ready. i understand that this is android based, which i am fine with, but don't know where exactly to start. the above links give me tools, but not suggestions how to implement

Comment: Just added link for Cordova Plugin. This plugin project has how-to with example in readme. Hope this helps.

Comment: +1! This looks like what i've been searching for. hopefully this will work. will update this if it does. thank you for your help!